# With CORBA what is the difference between the -port 1050 -ORBInitialPort 1055 options?

Tags: corba

When executing orbd there appears to be two different port options.

> orbd -port 1050 -ORBInitialPort 1055

What are the differences between these two ports?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/idl/orbd.html), a google search should have given you this also